# Using Group by with x amount of elements

Tags: c#, linq

Here's a list, think of it as rows and columns where rows are going down and columns are side ways. the column count will always be the same for all rows.

```
      var dataValues = new List<List<string>>()
        {
            //row 1
            new List<string>(){"A","12","X","P8" },
            //row 2
            new List<string>(){"B","13","Y","P7" },
            //row 3
            new List<string>(){"C","12","Y","P6" },
            //row 4
            new List<string>(){"A","14","X","P5" },
            //....
            new List<string>(){"D","15","Z","P4" },
            new List<string>(){"A","13","X","P3" },
            new List<string>(){"B","14","Y","P2" },
            new List<string>(){"C","13","Z","P1" },
        };
```

The user providers a list of indexes to group by.

```
var userParam= new List<int>() { 0, 2 };
```

my question is how do i dynamically group dataValues by the userParam where user param is n amount of index. In the example above it will gorup by the first column and the 3rd. However the index can change and the amount of indexes can change aswell

example

```
var userParam2 = new List<int>() { 0, 2};
var userParam3 = new List<int>() { 0};
var userParam4 = new List<int>() { 0,1,2};
```

i know how to group by when i know how many indexes there will be (the the case below it's 2 index parameters), however when it's dynamic (x amount) then i do not know how to do this

```
 var result = dataValues.GroupBy(e => new { G1 = e[userParam2 [0]], G2 = e[userParam2 [1]] });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Custom Comparer to achieve this :
1 - Declaration of `GroupByComparer` that inherit from `IEqualityComparer` :

```
public class GroupByComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<string>>
{
    private static List<int> _intList;
    public GroupByComparer(List<int> intList)
    {
        _intList = intList;
    }
    public bool Equals(List<string> x, List<string> y)
    {
        foreach (int item in _intList)
        {
            if (x[item] != y[item])
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<string> obj)
    {
        int hashCode = 0;
        foreach (int item in _intList)
        {
            hashCode ^= obj[item].GetHashCode() + item;
        }

        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

2 - Call group by with `EqualityComparer` like :

```
var userParam = new List<int>() { 0, 2 };

var result = dataValues.GroupBy(e => e, new GroupByComparer(userParam));
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: You should really short circuit the equals method to return as soon as you find unequal items, rather than continuing to iterate through the rest.  Also, your hash code algorithm generates the same hash code for lists with the same items in a different order, resulting in much higher collision rates than you'll see with other algorithms that don't have that property.

Comment: thanks i've accepted this answer, i can work on optimisations, so that's fine i just didnt have an idea of how to do dynamic groupings

Comment: @Servy you're right, i updated ``equals`` method, i will see for `GetHashCode`

Answer (score 0):

I believe i have something but this looks slow please let me know if there is anyway better of doing this.

```
        var userParams = new List<int>() { 0, 2 };

        var dataValues = new List<List<string>>()
        {
            new List<string>(){"A","12","X","P8" },
            new List<string>(){"B","13","Y","P7" },
            new List<string>(){"C","12","Y","P6" },
            new List<string>(){"A","14","X","P5" },
            new List<string>(){"D","15","Z","P4" },
            new List<string>(){"A","13","X","P3" },
            new List<string>(){"B","14","Y","P2" },
            new List<string>(){"C","13","Z","P1" },
        };

        var result = new List<(List<string> Key, List<List<string>> Values)>();
        result.Add((new List<string>(), dataValues));

        for (int index = 0; index < userParams.Count; index++)
        {
            var currentResult = new List<(List<string> Key, List<List<string>> Values)>();
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                foreach (var newGroup in item.Values.GroupBy(e => e[userParams[index]]))
                {
                    var newKey = item.Key.ToList();
                    newKey.Add(newGroup.Key);
                    currentResult.Add((newKey, newGroup.ToList()));
                }
            }
            result = currentResult;
        }

            foreach(var res in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Key: {string.Join(@"\", res.Key)}, Values: {string.Join(" | ", res.Values.Select(e=> string.Join(",",e)))}");
            }
```

final result

```
Key: A\X, Values: A,12,X,P8 | A,14,X,P5 | A,13,X,P3
Key: B\Y, Values: B,13,Y,P7 | B,14,Y,P2
Key: C\Y, Values: C,12,Y,P6
Key: C\Z, Values: C,13,Z,P1
Key: D\Z, Values: D,15,Z,P4
```